# Looking for DPA 5100 Case Suggestions

Tags: bag, dpa

Looking for ideas of housing a DPA 5100 While in transit.  Currently have it sitting in the mfg cardboard box inside of my larger FX kit pelican.  Looking for something new and more sturdy as the cardboard box is getting old.  I would like it to nest within the 1650.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a smallish psuedo pelican case locally quite cheaply, which fits both my TR606 and Bassbot and it has that foam which you can form by plucking to fit... Not really an answer, its probably a bit big to have inside a larger pelican case..... but a related question: what do you think of the DPA 5100 in use? Whats been your favourite use of it so far with great results?

Comment: @Tim  I am going to be honest here.  I do not have much experience with the 5100. I recently started a new job at a Dub stage here, and one of my duties is to maintain the FX kits.  I have no personal experience with this mic.  I can say I prefer using it than upmixings/forcing stereo tracks into a 5.1 environment.  This job has moved me into the 5.1 field. :)   I could give you my boss' opinion on it, but it is not mine.  I am hoping to start taking out the smaller kit to record random things and use all the fancy toys they have and make my own opinions on them.  